# How to Get Blazor Component HTML Source Code

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Is it possible to get the HTML source code of a server-side Blazor component/page? For example, to generate a PDF for any given Blazor page, I would need it's entire HTML source code rendered. Since it's SPA, each individual page does not really have any visible HTML source code ... Thanks!

Comment: What’s the reason that something like window.print() doesn’t work for your use case?

Comment: I need to generate the PDF and save it somewhere, not just for user to print it out.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to get all the html source code. Syncfusion Essential PDF is a .NET Core PDF library can help you create, read, and edit PDF documents in Blazor.

1. Install the NuGet package: Syncfusion.PDF.Net.Core
2. Create a new cs file named `ExportService` under Data folder and include the following namespaces in the file.

   ```
   using Syncfusion.Pdf;
   using Syncfusion.Pdf.Graphics;
   using Syncfusion.Pdf.Grid;
   using Syncfusion.Drawing;
   ```
3. Add the following method in the ExportService class.

   ```
   //Export weather data to PDF document.
   public MemoryStream CreatePdf(WeatherForecast[] forecasts)
   {
     if (forecasts == null)
     {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("Forecast cannot be null");
    }
   //Create a new PDF document
   using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument())
   {

    int paragraphAfterSpacing = 8;
    int cellMargin = 8;

    //Add page to the PDF document
    PdfPage page = pdfDocument.Pages.Add();

    //Create a new font
    PdfStandardFont font = new PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.TimesRoman, 16);

    //Create a text element to draw a text in PDF page
    PdfTextElement title = new PdfTextElement("Weather Forecast", font, PdfBrushes.Black);
    PdfLayoutResult result = title.Draw(page, new PointF(0, 0));


    PdfStandardFont contentFont = new PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.TimesRoman, 12);
    PdfTextElement content = new PdfTextElement("component generate the pdf", contentFont, PdfBrushes.Black);
    PdfLayoutFormat format = new PdfLayoutFormat();
    format.Layout = PdfLayoutType.Paginate;

    //Draw a text to the PDF document
    result = content.Draw(page, new RectangleF(0, result.Bounds.Bottom + paragraphAfterSpacing, page.GetClientSize().Width, page.GetClientSize().Height), format);

    //Create a PdfGrid
    PdfGrid pdfGrid = new PdfGrid();
    pdfGrid.Style.CellPadding.Left = cellMargin;
    pdfGrid.Style.CellPadding.Right = cellMargin;

    //Applying built-in style to the PDF grid
    pdfGrid.ApplyBuiltinStyle(PdfGridBuiltinStyle.GridTable4Accent1);

    //Assign data source
    pdfGrid.DataSource = forecasts;

    pdfGrid.Style.Font = contentFont;

    //Draw PDF grid into the PDF page
    pdfGrid.Draw(page, new Syncfusion.Drawing.PointF(0, result.Bounds.Bottom + paragraphAfterSpacing));

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        //Saving the PDF document into the stream
        pdfDocument.Save(stream);
        //Closing the PDF document
        pdfDocument.Close(true);
        return stream;

     }
    }
   }
   ```
4. Register your service in the ConfigureServices.

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       //...
       services.AddSingleton<ExportService>();
   }
   ```
5. Inject ExportService into FetchData.razor.

   ```
   @inject ExportService exportService
   @inject Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime JS
   @using System.IO
   ```
6. In this component, give one button.

   ```
   <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@ExportToPdf">Export to PDF</button>
   ```
7. Add this method in FetchData.razor.

   ```
   @functions
   {

    protected async Task ExportToPdf()
    {
      using (MemoryStream excelStream = exportService.CreatePdf(forecasts))
      {
        await JS.SaveAs("Sample.pdf", excelStream.ToArray());
       }
     }
   }
   ```
8. Create the static class.

   ```
   public static class FileUtil
   {
      public static ValueTask<object> SaveAs(this IJSRuntime js, string filename, byte[] data)
   => js.InvokeAsync<object>(
       "saveAsFile",
       filename,
       Convert.ToBase64String(data));
    }
   ```
9. Add the following JavaScript function in the _Host.cshtml.

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function saveAsFile(filename, bytesBase64) {
        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            //Download document in Edge browser
            var data = window.atob(bytesBase64);
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            var blob = new Blob([bytes.buffer], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        }
        else {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = filename;
            link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + bytesBase64;
            document.body.appendChild(link); // Needed for Firefox
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
       }
     </script>
   ```

Last, you can get the genereated pdf.

[image]

Comment: You only need to add this NuGet package: Syncfusion.PDF.Net.Core, it does not require a license.

Comment: @Karney. It does - https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/products/fileformats